# Embedded ttf font in itext program not getting loaded in a Linux machine

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

In my program I use something like this -

```
String arielunicodePath = config_Folder_Path+File.separatorChar
        +"resources"+File.separatorChar + "ARIALUNI.ttf";
arielunicodebase =  BaseFont.createFont(arielunicodePath, BaseFont.WINANSI,  BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I have put the ARIALUNI.ttf file in the correct location in my project.

Its working fine on my windows machine. But when i deploy it to our Linux server, the font creating command above fails with below error -

```
java.io.IOException: /x/programs/reporttransformationmsgd/config/resources/ARIALUNI.ttf not found as file or resource.
```

I confirmed that the file is available on the exact location the program is looking for.

What am I missing here?

Comment: *I confirmed that the file is available on the exact location the program is looking for.* - have you also checked for upper/lower case equality? Linux file systems generally are case aware, and on my Windows I find a `ARIALUNI.TTF`, not a `ARIALUNI.ttf`...

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the issue. nice catch :)

Comment: Glad to help. I made the comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When developing on Windows and deploying on Linux, one sometimes forgets that Linux generally handles file names in a case-sensitive manner while Windows does not.

In the case at hand the file name the program sought for was `ARIALUNI.ttf` while the font file actually (just like in the Windows fonts folder) was named `ARIALUNI.TTF`.

Testing on Windows the lower case extension meant no problem while on Linux it gave rise to the *not found as file or resource* `IOException`.